# Can I disable Django DEBUG mode for specific functions so as to avoid generating the detailed error page?

Tags: django, debugging

One particular function in my Django server performs a lot of computation during a request and that computation involves a lot of local variables. When an error is thrown during the computation, Django spits out all the function's local variables onto the error page. This process takes Django 10-15 seconds (presumably because of the number/size of my local variables)...

I want to disable the error page for just that particular function, so I can get to see the simple stacktrace faster.

I tried using the [sensitive_variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/) decorator but that doesn't do anything when DEBUG=True.

I also tried simply catching the exception and throwing a new exception:

```
try:
    return mymodule.performComputations(self)
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(repr(e))
```

but Django still manages to output all the local variables from the performComputations method.

My only option right now is to set DEBUG=False globally anytime I'm actively developing that particular code flow / likely to encounter errors. Any other suggestions? Thanks!